# How to get position of iterated element angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, position, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have iterated dropdown and I would like to know what is the position of each of these dropdowns when I click on it.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="animal in vm.animals">
  {{animal}}
  <btn-group uib-dropdown>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm uib-dropdown-toggle
            ng-click="vm.checkPosition($event)">{{vm.test}}
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
      <a class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="dog in vm.dogs">
        {{dog}}
      </a>
  </btn>
```

```
function checkPosition($event) {
  // I tried use here $event.target.el.getBoundingClientRect().top, but this 
  // position isnt element which I clicked, but propably first element with
  // this class
}
```

Comment: you mean the `index` position in the array that is being iterated ?

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) describe, you have access to certain variables inside of your `ng-repeat`.

For example `$first` is true only for the first element, `$last` only for the last one.
What you are looking for is `$index`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `index` of the array you can use `$index` as **Scorpioo590** mentioned. which in angularjs will give you the item's index in the array that is used in the `ng-repeat` you can use it like this:

```
ng-click="vm.checkPosition($event, $index)"
```

```
function checkPosition($event, index) {
 console.log(index);
}
```